# Porque ya no funciona despues de cerrarlo y volver a abrirlo?

Tags: python

Cuando lo probe antes funciono, solo que mostraba un "none" al final, pero a la hora de revisarlo ya no corre y aparece 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer caundo quiero pasar de la cantidad de estudiantes.
Al parecer la linea que contiene `for j in range(k):` salta el error, pero no logro decifrarlo.

```
def validar():
    while True:
        k = int(input("Cual es la cantidad de alumnos: \n"))
        if k <= 0:
            continue
        else:
            break
        #Endif
    #Endwhile
#Enddef

def validar2():
    while True:
        c = float(input("Ingrese el costo de las matriculas: "))
        if c <= 0:
            continue
        else:
            break
        #Endif
    #Endwhile
#Enddef

h = 0
c = validar2()
k = validar()
for j in range(k):
    for i in range(10):
        x = float(input(f"Ingrese la nota {i+1} del alumno {j+1}: "))
        h+=x
        o = (h/10) 
    print(f"Promedio del alumno {j+1} es: ",o)
    if o >= 9.1:
            e = c - (c*0.15)
    elif o <= 9 or o >= 7:
            e = c - (c*0.08)
    else:
            e = c - (c*0.06)
    e+=e
        #Endif
    #Endfor
#Endfor
print(f"El total a parar por {k} alumnos es de: {e}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan los `return` en las funciones. Sin un `return valor` la función retorna, pero no devuelve ningun valor.

Debes reemplazar los `break` for `return k` o la variable del caso.

```
def validar():
    while True:
        k = int(input("Cual es la cantidad de alumnos: \n"))
        if k <= 0:
            continue
        else:
            return k
        #Endif
    #Endwhile
#Enddef

def validar2():
    while True:
        c = float(input("Ingrese el costo de las matriculas: "))
        if c <= 0:
            continue
        else:
            return c
        #Endif
    #Endwhile
#Enddef

h = 0
c = validar2()
k = validar()
for j in range(k):
    for i in range(10):
        x = float(input(f"Ingrese la nota {i+1} del alumno {j+1}: "))
        h+=x
        o = (h/10)
    print(f"Promedio del alumno {j+1} es: ",o)
    if o >= 9.1:
            e = c - (c*0.15)
    elif o <= 9 or o >= 7:
            e = c - (c*0.08)
    else:
            e = c - (c*0.06)
    e+=e
        #Endif
    #Endfor
#Endfor
print(f"El total a parar por {k} alumnos es de: {e}")
```